# cumulative count returning more rows than expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

base_table

```
   eom         account_id      closings  checkouts
    2018-11-01       1              21       147
    2018-12-01       1              20       214
```

calendar_table

```
month       account_id
2020-11-01       1
2014-04-01       1
```

Based on two tables, above, I would like to create a month-by-month cumulative closings and checkouts.
The calendar_table contains the months the account id is active. Thus, it is used as the main table (in the from clause).

```
with 
base_table as (
    select eom, account_id, closings, checkouts 
    from base_table bt 
    where account_id in (3,30,122,152,161,179)
                                    )               
,calendar_table as (
        select ct.month, c.external_id as account_id
        from calendar_table ct 
        left join customers c
            on c.id = ct.organization_id 
        where account_id in (3,30,122,152,161,179)
                    )
,cumulative_table as (
    select  ct."month"
            ,list.account_id
            ,coalesce(bt.closings,0) as closings
            ,coalesce(sum(closings) OVER (PARTITION BY list.account_id
                                         ORDER BY ct."month"
                                         rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),0)
                                         as cum_closings
            ,coalesce(bt.checkouts,0) as checkouts
            ,coalesce(sum(checkouts) OVER (PARTITION BY list.account_id
                                         ORDER BY ct."month"
                                         rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),0)
                                         AS cum_checkouts
    from calendar_table ct 
    cross join (select distinct account_id from base_table) list
    left join base_table bt
        on bt.account_id = list.account_id and bt.eom = ct.month
                    )
  select * 
  from cumulative_table
```

The query above returns a cumulative table that contains duplications, probably because of the cross join.

```
month     account_id closings cum_closings checkouts cum_checkouts
01/11/17      1         20          20         282         282
01/11/17      1         20          40         282         564
01/11/17      1         20          60         282         846
01/12/17      1         17          77         346         1192
01/12/17      1         17          94         346         1538
01/12/17      1         17          111        346         1884
```

I expect the query to return one month per account id.

```
 month     account_id closings cum_closings checkouts cum_checkouts
    01/11/17      1         20          20         282         282
    01/12/17      1         17          37         346         628
```

Comment: Please provide proper table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) showing data types and constraints - including the table `customers`. And sample data matching your expected result. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can do more simple :

```
WITH list AS
( select bt.eom, bt.account_id, bt.closings, bt.checkouts
       , ct.month, ct.organization_id
    from base_table bt 
   inner join calendar_table ct
      on ct.account_id = bt.account_id 
   where bt.account_id in (3,30,122,152,161,179)
)
select l.month, c.external_id as account_id
     , coalesce(l.closings,0) as closings
     , coalesce( sum(l.closings) OVER (PARTITION BY l.account_id
                                       ORDER BY l."month"
                                       rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
               , 0
               ) as cum_closings
     , coalesce(l.checkouts,0) as checkouts
     , coalesce( sum(l.checkouts) OVER (PARTITION BY l.account_id
                                        ORDER BY l."month"
                                        rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
               , 0
               ) AS cum_checkouts
  from list as l
  left join customers c
    on c.id = l.organization_id ;
```